# Jenkins: getting GIT_COMMIT from downstream job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline which triggers some downstream jobs defined as multibranch pipelines. I would like to get the commit of the job being run, which is usually present in `env.GIT_COMMIT`.

Besides dumping the `env.GIT_COMMIT` variable to a file, and registering that file as a build artifact, is there a way to get the commit of the build? I have looked into the [Run class](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/class-use/Run.html), but I don't see a clear way to get the commit through that route.

Here is an excerpt of my pipeline, containing the parts triggering the downstream job and retreiving the artifact:

```groovy
retry(count: 3) {
  build job: "${jobNameFrontend}", wait: true, parameters: [
    [$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'PACKAGE',    value: true],
    [$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'SKIP_TESTS', value: params.SKIP_TESTS]
    ]
}
copyArtifacts projectName: "${jobNameFrontend}", filter: 'frontend.zip', fingerprintArtifacts: true, target: 'dist'
unzip dir: "${SOURCE_DIR}", glob: '', zipFile: './dist/frontend.zip'
```

Comment: If you only need the hash you could use the *somewhat dirty*: Job Build/Run description via the `return` of the `build(...)` command (an `RunWrapper` Object). You can set the new Job's Build/Run Description via `currentBuild.description = '...'`. Alternatively you can simply add an artifact or file to `frontend.zip` containing the needed data

Comment: @Sir.Chefcoq If you write up an answer (You can almost copy mine and i'll delete that)

Answer (score 0):

I added

```groovy
writeJSON file: "${BUILD_DIR}/frontend_meta.json", json: ['branch': env.GIT_BRANCH, 'commit': env.GIT_COMMIT]
```

to the build just before the

```groovy
zip archive: true, defaultExcludes: false, dir: "${BUILD_DIR}", exclude: '', glob: '', zipFile: 'frontend.zip'
```

line